OpenCV c++ namedWindow assertion error !winname.empty()
I'm new to C++ and trying to create a simple window to display images using OpenCV, using the namedWindow() function.
My code fails almost immediately upon calling namedWindow, with the message that the assertion "!winname.empty()" failed.
This is my code:
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    try {
        namedWindow("Animation Engine", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    }
    catch (Exception& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

This builds without issue, but fails on execution when calling namedWindow() with the message "error: (-215:Assertion failed) !winname.empty() in function 'cv::namedWindow'".
I am supplying a name to the window exactly as shown in OpenCV's documentation, so what could possibly be going wrong here?

My guess is incompatible binaries  / using msvc binaries for MinGW.

Just for reference, I tested your code on my machine and it works, so it is indeed probably some linker issue.

@FlorianEchtler I reinstalled opencv, also tried installing 4.9 instead of 4.10. Also reinstalled visual studio, and recreated the environment from scratch multiple times following tutorials like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unSce_GPwto
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUjamcyuKT4.
Still the exact same error. I figured out that if I remove the space in the title, a window launches, but the title is gibberish characters and the program immediately crashes with c++ exception bad_alloc.

ah yes, that issue, all the symptoms are there. make sure you pair up debug with debug, release with release, never mix. we've been seeing this issue for a while. this question should be closed as a duplicate of one of the suitable older answered questions.

@ChristophRackwitz Yup, that was it, thank you. I was building in debug mode but I guess OpenCV was in release. Had only been researching the namedWindow assertion error, not the bad_alloc exception that started after making aforementioned changes, so hadn't noticed existing threads.

the clue was the gibberish text, but I started to suspect when the program claimed to have empty strings that shouldn't be empty. these two symptoms don't inherently point to the cause. you've got to know of the issue to spot it.
